# Python - How to find all number words in a phrase?

Tags: python, regex, numbers, cpu-word

I was wondering how you could possibly detect all number words in a phrase. For example

```
math_str = "one times one plus sin(one hundred fifty three) minus three billion"
getNumberWords(math_str) #Returns one, one, one hundred fifty three, three billion
```

Is there a regex pattern or something?

Comment: This won't be an easy task. And without your code to improve upon no one in here can do much.

Comment: Well, "three billion" could be matched as "three" and "billion"

Comment: If you know your inputs, you might want to have a look at [word2number](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/word2number)

Answer (score 1):

There is no shortcut for this as python does not understand English or human language, you need to have a list of words that are considered numeric words

```
math_str = "one times one plus sin(one hundred fifty three) minus three billion"
allowed = ['one', 'three', 'fifty', 'hundred', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion']

def getNumberWords(math_str):
    math_str = math_str.replace('(', ' ')
    math_str = math_str.replace(')', ' ')
    math_str = math_str.split()

    return [word for word in math_str if word in allowed]

print(getNumberWords(math_str))
```

in this example i just put in the number of words required to get your result, but you're going to fill in a lot of words(numeric) if you want your result to be accurate

Comment: Thanks! I guess this is the closest I'm going to get.